# I'm free Thursday / on Thursday

Tags: prepositions, ellipsis, time-words

Which one is right?

> **1** I'm free Thursday.
>   **2** I'm free on Thursday.

I thought if you want to say that something happens during a particular day, you should use *on*, as in '*They’ll be here on Tuesday*.' But I came across the title sentence without *on*, and now I don't know exactly when to use *on* before a specific day and when not to!

Comment: If someone is asking you to help them move, the correct phrasing is, "I'm BUSY on Thursday". :-)

Comment: Or: "I'm busy Thursday."

Answer (score 6):

Actually, even for the example that you gave, "on" really isn't necessary:

You could have either

> They’ll be here on Tuesday.

OR

> They'll be here Tuesday.

Same goes for "free on Thursday" vs "free Thursday." In my experience, both are used more or less interchangeably.

Comment: So when is it necessary to use _on_ ?

Comment: @MJF That is actually a complicated question in my mind. For example, if you're talking about an event, "The game will be on Friday" sounds MUCH better than, "The game will be Friday." You may need to wait for someone else to expand on general rules for "on," because I can't seem to come up with a general rule.

Comment: I've been thinking about this for a little while and I can't come up with a construction that seems to *require* the "on". It is definitely preferred in some cases (as in Alex's comment), but not required in any situation I can think of right now.

Comment: Well, hearing that from native speakers is a relief. Thanks.

Comment: Umm, for some reason, the versions without *on* sound very strange to me.

Comment: @AloisMahdal Even the title? I can give you five more _on_-less sentences from my search through the web in American texts.

Comment: @MJF I'm not arguing; just that in last 10+ years or so, as an IT specialist, I've been spending significant part of my days reading (and learning) US/non-US English texts (from internet articles to manuals to  company email lists) and I still wouldn't feel like omitting the *on*.  From that I assume: if that's common, maybe the IT industry branch is a bit different...?

Comment: Omitting the "on" is just informal.

Comment: @AloisMahdal They sound perfectly natural to me.

Comment: I prefer # 2.I'm free on Thursday.